# Maya 2015: fit view issue when create custom node

Tags: maya, maya-api

I have a simple scene like this:

[image]

Where CTRL_set and CTRL_setsubControl are two custom nodes. When I press F for focus to selection, it gives me this:

[image]

The mesh go far far away also if I select the mesh (and not the custom node) before press F. This issue also occurs when I press A.

How can I solve it maintaining the same structure of nodes?

Comment: It may be a bad bounding box calculation in your custom nodes

Comment: It seems you're right. The bounding box of CTRL_set is huge.  Instead, bounding box of CTRL_setsubControl has the size of child group. These two custom nodes are of the same type, so why CTRL_set doesn't get bb size of child node? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that CTRL_set node has huge bounding box.

I solve it turning off the CTRL_set visibility: now the bbox has finite size and the node still works fine. Finally, when I press A (or F with CTRL_set selected) the view fit the scene as usual.

(This problem occurs in Maya 2015 SP6 Extension 1, not in SP2)